# fluid div width

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="post">
    <img src="image.png"/>
    <div class="postbox">
        some content here
    </div>
</div>
```

How do i make `.postbox' expand it's width to the max possible with with respect to the width of the image or without the image?

```
#post{
width:569px;
overflow:hidden
}
#post img, #post .postbox{
float:left
}
```

I tried `width:100%` to `.postbox` but it's taking up the whole width.

http://jsfiddle.net/FTY4k/

Comment: Don't float it left is how. You could float the `<img>` right instead?

Comment: @JamWaffles that still doesn't take up the whole width-width of the image

Answer (score 2):

```
.postbox { width:100% }
```

This will make the div the same width as the container

Comment: Yes it stretches to the width of the parent making not inline with the image.

Comment: Yep saw that after. Shouldn't post while drunk. Answer withdrawn.

Comment: I took your question to mean expanding the div to the max with respect to the post div. As mentioned before, if you remove the float from the post box its width with be 100% and flow around the floated image.

http://jsfiddle.net/FTY4k/1/

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't mess up your layout, you could float the image, but not the div.

```
#post{
width:569px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#post img{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: superb, thanks! But wait, it's still taking up the whole width, only the text was adjusting.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS `float` pulls the element out of the flow. In a sense, your `img` and `div class="postbox"` a no longer contained in the `div id="post"` even though it is still their *parent* in the DOM tree.

You can try setting those to `inline-block` instead of using `float`, or float them together withing an inner div and have a `clear`, all contained within `id="post"`

More details depends somewhat on your bigger picture of what you're trying to do in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like these I like to use [Nicole Sullivan](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/)'s `media` object abstraction. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B8UUG/) (for reference).

HTML:

```
<div class="media">
  <a href="#" class="img"><img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" /></a>
  <div class="bd">lorem dolor...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.media {margin:10px;}
.media, .bd {overflow:hidden; _overflow:visible; zoom:1;}
.media .img {float:left; margin-right: 10px;}
.media .img img {display:block;}
.media .imgExt {float:right; margin-left: 10px;}
```